# Promise.all() resolves immediately

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, vue.js

I'm trying to take some action after upload completion of multiple images, using [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html).

However, the code after `then` runs before the code being dispatched.

What am I confusing here?

```
  submit_all_images({ dispatch, rootState }) {
    const imageFileArray = rootState.imageStore.imageFileArray 
    var promiseArray = []

    for ( var imageFile of imageFileArray ) {
      promiseArray.push(dispatch('get_signed_request', imageFile))
    }

    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(results => {
        console.log("finished with results: " + results)
        return dispatch('submit_entire_form')
      });
  },
  get_signed_request ({ dispatch, commit, state }, imgFile) {
    const requestObject = {imageName: imgFile.name, imageType: `${imgFile.type}`}
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/sign-s3', requestObject)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.body.signedRequest && response.body.awsImageUrl) {
          const signedRequest = response.body.signedRequest
          const awsImageUrl = response.body.awsImageUrl
          dispatch('upload_file', { imgFile, signedRequest, awsImageUrl })
        } else {
          alert('Could not get signed URL.');
        }
    }, error => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + error)
    })
  },

  upload_file ({ dispatch, commit, state}, { imgFile, signedRequest, awsImageUrl }) {
    axios.put(signedRequest, imgFile, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': imgFile.type}
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('finished uploading file: ' + imgFile.name )
      commit(types.UPDATE_LICENSE_IMG_URLS, awsImageUrl)
    }, error => {
      alert("fail")
      console.log(error)
    })
  },
```

Comment: It's a good questions, but if you're interested, it's already been done and it's ready to go http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Are you positive that `(dispatch('get_signed_request', imageFile))` returns a promise? I would check that first, if you are using Redux dispatches dont return promises

Comment: I'm using Vuex and pretty sure it does: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html

Comment: @RonRoyston If I understand correctly, this is for the loading of images in the DOM. I'm trying to hook into successful uploading of images to a server

Comment: I see.  You using node.js?

Comment: @softcode, sadly it doesn't always return a promise, it seems to depend on your action: [see the source code](//github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/index.js#L107). Have you logged `promiseArray` to check its content?

Comment: @Thomas wow nice catch. Am I reading source correctly: If there is no action type it doesn't return a promise ? And yes I logged it and it is indeed an array of promises.  Any ideas?

Comment: @softcode if there's no action for this type, it returns `undefined`, but the more important thing is, if there's only a single entry for that action it returns whatever this function returns; Promise or not. Only if there are multiple entries, it uses `Promise.all()` and therefore **guarantees** to return a Promise.

Comment: @Thomas so if there's a single entry, `Promise.all()` won't run? What do you suggest?

Comment: @softcode, I was only talking about vuex#dispatch method. It utilizes `Promise.all` only if there are multiple entries for a particular action, but *may* return a non-promise value if there are `<2` entries for an action type. This has no impact on the `Promise.all` in your code; it would have impacted your code only as your `promiseArray` may not contain promises; But you've checked that.

Comment: How do you determine that the `then()` part is running early? Are you sure that your logging and interpretation is correct? And since I don't know anything about your `get_signed_request` action, are you sure that it resolves *after* **everything** is done? And doesn't have pending work when the promise resolves. The code you've posted should work properly.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure. I'm fairly new to Promises, so I have updated the question with the `get_signed_request` action and the action it itself calls, for clarity sake. Any further help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, since I have no experience with vuex, but I guess you're missing a few `return` statements.

```
get_signed_request({ dispatch, commit, state }, imgFile){
    const requestObject = {imageName: imgFile.name, imageType: `${imgFile.type}`}
    //here
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/sign-s3', requestObject)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.body.signedRequest && response.body.awsImageUrl) {
                const signedRequest = response.body.signedRequest
                const awsImageUrl = response.body.awsImageUrl
                //here
                return dispatch('upload_file', { imgFile, signedRequest, awsImageUrl })
            } else {
                alert('Could not get signed URL.');
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log("ERROR: " + error)
        })
},

upload_file({ dispatch, commit, state}, { imgFile, signedRequest, awsImageUrl }){
    //here
    return axios.put(signedRequest, imgFile, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': imgFile.type}
    }).then(response => {
        console.log('finished uploading file: ' + imgFile.name )
        //and here
        return commit(types.UPDATE_LICENSE_IMG_URLS, awsImageUrl)
    }, error => {
        alert("fail")
        console.log(error)
    })
},
```

So that `get_signed_request` returns a Promise that resolves only after `axios.post().then()` is done, wich depends on first resolving `dispatch('upload_file', ...)`

And the same for `upload_file` depending on resolving `axios.put().then()`depending on `commit(types.UPDATE_LICENSE_IMG_URLS, awsImageUrl)`

Comment: Yes it worked. Slightly confused though. Should actions with async tasks always return promises in this fashion ? Even when they're called alone ? @Thomas

Comment: @softcode, are you sure that they will always be called alone? Even in the future? The Promise is built wether you return it or not.